# Jquery ui Image cycler

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-ui

I have been developing using jquery ui. Today I got stuck on image cycler. The default image slider code is for 3 pictures. I have 30 pictures on my site and I have to cycle it using ui-cycler fluently but it's not possible. To make it work I have to click on a static picture X time's before image cycler comes into play. Here is the cycler code for 3 images:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        // TODO refactor into a widget and get rid of these plugin methods
        $.fn.left = function( using ) {
            return this.position({
                my: "right middle",
                at: "left+25 middle",
                of: "#container",
                collision: "none",
                using: using
            });
        };
        $.fn.right = function( using ) {
            return this.position({
                my: "left middle",
                at: "right-25 middle",
                of: "#container",
                collision: "none",
                using: using
            });
        };
        $.fn.center = function( using ) {
            return this.position({
                my: "center middle",
                at: "center middle",
                of: "#container",
                using: using
            });
        };

        $( "img:eq(0)" ).left();
        $( "img:eq(1)" ).center();
        $( "img:eq(2)" ).right();

        function animate( to ) {
            $( this ).stop( true, false ).animate( to );
        }
        function next( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $( "img:eq(2)" ).center( animate );
            $( "img:eq(1)" ).left( animate )
            $( "img:eq(0)" ).right().appendTo( "#container" );
        }
        function previous( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $( "img:eq(0)" ).center( animate );
            $( "img:eq(1)" ).right( animate );
            $( "img:eq(2)" ).left().prependTo( "#container" );
        }
        $( "#previous" ).click( previous );
        $( "#next" ).click( next );

        $( "img" ).click(function( event ) {
            $( "img" ).index( this ) === 0 ? previous( event ) : next( event );
        });

        $( window ).resize(function() {
            $( "img:eq(0)" ).left( animate );
            $( "img:eq(1)" ).center( animate );
            $( "img:eq(2)" ).right( animate );
        });
    });
    </script>
```

And here is my picture reference html:

```
    <div id="container">

        <img class = "slide"  src="images/slide1.jpg"  alt="Race2"/>
        <img class="slide" src="images/slide2.jpg"  alt="Akshay Kumar"/>
        <img class = "slide" src = "images/slide_eng1.jpg" alt = "English Roller"/>
        <img class = "slide" src = "images/slide_eng2.jpg" alt = "Bruce Willis"/>
<!-- still many image -->
    </div>
```

what should i do to make it work?

Comment: I tried adding many things, like numbering img:eq(x):aligner, but did not work for anything. Error console in mozilla does not display any errors no matter what i do

Comment: there are a bunch of plugins already available for this sort of thing have you tried using an existing product such as bxSlider?

Comment: Can you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example?

Comment: I'l try and no I dont want bxSlider, the slider provided by jquery is good

Comment: I tried but couldnt do it properly. Actually this is the code. I have posted it correctly, please add more images and let me know what is happening

Answer (score 0):

First you have to hide the rest of the images (index 3 and up) using the function ext_right, and you should change the append and prepend as shown below:

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            // TODO refactor into a widget and get rid of these plugin methods
            $.fn.left = function (using) {
                return this.position({
                    my: "right middle",
                    at: "left+25 middle",
                    of: "#image_container",
                    collision: "none",
                    using: using
                });
            };
            $.fn.right = function (using) {
                return this.position({
                    my: "left middle",
                    at: "right-25 middle",
                    of: "#image_container",
                    collision: "none",
                    using: using
                });
            };
            $.fn.center = function (using) {
                return this.position({
                    my: "center middle",
                    at: "center middle",
                    of: "#image_container",
                    using: using
                });
            };

            $.fn.ext_right = function () {
                return this.position({
                    my: "left middle",
                    at: "right+30 middle",
                    of: "#image_container",
                    collision: "none",
                });
            };

            $("img.cycler:eq(0)").left();
            $("img.cycler:eq(1)").center();
            $("img.cycler:eq(2)").right();

            /*Place the rest of the image_container images hidden to the right*/
            $("img.cycler:gt(2)").ext_right();

            function animate(to) {
                $(this).stop(true, false).animate(to);
            }

            function next(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $("img.cycler:eq(2)").center(animate);
                $("img.cycler:eq(1)").left(animate)
                //$("img.cycler:eq(0)").right().appendTo("#image_container");                
                $("img.cycler:eq(3)").right();
                $("img.cycler:eq(0)").ext_right().appendTo("#image_container");
            }
            function previous(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $("img.cycler:eq(0)").center(animate);
                $("img.cycler:eq(1)").right(animate);                                
                //$("img.cycler:eq(2)").left().prependTo("#image_container");
                $("img.cycler:eq(2)").ext_right();
                $("img.cycler:last").left().prependTo("#image_container");                                
            }

            $("#previous").click(previous);
            $("#next").click(next);

            $("img.cycler").click(function (event) {
                $("img.cycler").index(this) === 0 ? previous(event) : next(event);
            });

            $(window).resize(function () {
                $("img.cycler:eq(0)").left(animate);
                $("img.cycler:eq(1)").center(animate);
                $("img.cycler:eq(2)").right(animate);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Here are the images:

```
<div id="image_container">                    
                    <img class="cycler" src="images/flight.jpg" width="512" height="307" alt="flight" />
                    <img class="cycler" src="images/rocket.jpg" width="300" height="353" alt="rocket" />
                    <img class="cycler" src="images/earth.jpg" width="458" height="308" alt="earth" /> 
                    <img class="cycler" src="images/high_tatras.jpg" width="512" height="307" alt="flight" />
                    <img class="cycler" src="images/high_tatras2.jpg" width="300" height="353" alt="rocket" />
                    <img class="cycler" src="images/high_tatras3.jpg" width="458" height="308" alt="earth" />                    
                <a id="previous" href="#">Previous</a>  <a id="next" href="#">Next</a>
</div>
```